# Brackets cause error in Send-MailMessage -Attachment

Tags: email, powershell, wildcard, attachment, brackets

I am working on a script that gets the oldest log file in a folder, mails it to me and then deletes the file.

Getting the file name and deleting it afterwards works but, when a log file contains [ ] brackets, it fails sending the mail, while the file still gets deleted...

I know that brackets are wildcards and that I need to rename the files before trying to attach them but, I am not an experienced Powershell scripter and could not get examples working with my code... Could someone help me on my way?

My code:

```
$Item = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\backup log" -filter "*.log" | Sort CreationTime | select -First 1
Send-MailMessage -to "Jason <jason@company.com>" -from "Backupmaster <backupmaster@company.net>" -Subject "sync log: $($Item.Name)" -SmtpServer "172.24.1.x" -body "Attached is the sync log.`nFilename: $($Item.Name). `nNote that the oldest log is sent first, newer logs may arrive later.`nThis log will be deleted from the server after sending.`n`n-Backupmaster" -attachments "$($Item.FullName)"
Remove-Item $($Item.FullName)
```

-Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I'd expect it to work if you escape the brackets with `` ` ``:

```
$Attachment = $Item.FullName -replace "(\[|\])",'`$1'
```

And then

```
Send-MailMessage -Attachments $Attachment
```

Comment: That easy huh? :)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, for the simple solution to that problem.